# How do I access the auth information when I use router.get('/me', (res,req) => {})

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js

I haven't really found an answer to this question. But how do you get the nuxtjs/auth to work with mysql. More specifically, I was wondering specifically to get it to work with the '/me' route.

Like how do you access the "auth" information when you're doing something like:

My frontend login page

```
// #/pages/login.vue
this.$auth.loginWith('local', {
    data: {
    email: this.email,
    password: this.password
    }
}
```

My backend router

```
// #/api/router/authRouter.js
router.get('/me', (req,res) => {
    // code to check authentication and return the proper object
})
```

Comment: Have you tried looking at the documentation? https://auth.nuxtjs.org/schemes/local.html#options - what endpoint do you have set up for auth?

Comment: So atm the endpoints are /login, /me, and /register . I've read the documentation but I don't really get it

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry. I got it working... I had to change

```
 auth: {
    strategies: {
      local: {
        endpoints: {
          login: { url: 'auth/login', method: 'post', propertyName: 'data.token' },
          user: { url: 'auth/user', method: 'get', propertyName: false },
          logout: false
        }
      }
    },
}
```

to

```
 auth: {
    strategies: {
      local: {
        endpoints: {
          login: { url: 'auth/login', method: 'post', propertyName: 'token' },
          user: { url: 'auth/user', method: 'get', propertyName: false },
          logout: false
        }
      }
    },
}
```

My localstorage kept getting 'Bearer%undefined' instead of 'Bearer tokenkeystring' because my login payload returned

```
{
success: true,
token: 'tokenkeystring'
}
```

instead of

```
{
success:true,
data:
  {
    token: 'tokenkeystring'
  }
}
```